# Script to Rename selected object same as the active object plus a suffix

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, modifiers

[image]

So what I want basically is as follows:-
Basically I have two objects with different names. So lets say I select both of the Objects named "First" and "Second". So I make one of them named (First) as active selection. I want a script or addon which can rename the non-active object(named- Second) have the name of the first one but with a changeable suffix like say "_HP". So after applying the script I will have something like this.
Don't mind the annotation/painted names those are so u can easily see which object is named which. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: What if there are 3 or more objects in the scene?   Like a light or camera?  Or would that never happen?

Comment: Nah mostly I use max two objects:- One is high poly and other one is Low poly, if there will be a third I will try to rename it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bpy.context.active_object` and `bpy.context.selected_objects`.  The first tells you the object that is active — the one you want to use as the source of the name.  The second one tells you all of the selected objects, *including* the selected objects.  The simplest script to do what you want in this case is

```py
import bpy

name = bpy.context.active_object.name
suffix = "_toy"

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if not object.name == name:
        object.name = bpy.context.active_object.name + suffix
        break
```

You can enter this in the text editor, change the suffix string to whatever you like, and use the run key to run it.

It does have a bug, though.  If you have selected multiple objects, it will rename the first one in the list, and it might not be the one you want.

It's also inconvenient, in that you have to edit it every time you change the prefix.

You could turn it into an add-on with an object mode panel that you could use to set the suffix, of course:

```py
bl_info = {
    "name" : "renamer",
    "description" : "rename the selected object",
    "author" : "Marty",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy

from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty
from bpy.types import Panel

class RENAMER_OT_Message(Operator):
    """ Renamer operator
        Renames the other selected object to the same name as
        the active object, with a suffix added.
    """
    bl_idname = "renamer.rename"
    bl_label = "rename"
    bl_description = "rename the selected object"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        if not context.active_object:
           self.report({'ERROR'}, "No active object")
           return {'CANCELLED'}
        if len(context.selected_objects) != 2:
           self.report({'ERROR'}, "You must select two objects")
           return {'CANCELLED'}
        name = context.active_object.name
        for object in context.selected_objects:
            if not object.name == name:
                object.name = context.active_object.name + context.object.suffix
                break
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class RENAMER_PT_Panel(Panel):
    """ Renamer panel
        A panel to display the renamer operator
    """
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "renamer"
    bl_idname = "renamer.panel"
    bl_label = "rename selected"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column()
        col.prop(context.object, "suffix", text = "Suffix")
        col.operator("renamer.rename", text="rename")
        
classes = [
    RENAMER_OT_Message,
    RENAMER_PT_Panel,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
    bpy.types.Object.suffix= bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="suffix",
        description="Suffix to add to name",
        default="_HP",
    )
    
def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
    del bpy.types.Object.suffix
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: Oh wow, really that is almost what I wanted. Can I have one more change in this plz, Can you also make an another parameter, so the Active object can also have a suffix like "_LP". So after the rename script it will make two object : "First_LP"(active) and "First_HP".,

Comment: Thank you btw, I really appreciate you make a script and an addon too.

Comment: @NamanDeep Since you're apparently a new user to Blender StackExchange, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps accept my answer.

Comment: Your change request involves a lot more code than is reasonable for a StackExchange answer.  Using what I provided you should be able to make the changes to add the second parameter. It's a good way to learn, and StackExchange is meant to teach you how to do things, not do them for you.

Comment: Yeh, I actually did it, making some duplicate of the parameters and using the active object parameters to change its value and using that in execute funciton,. Thanks tho, I am still new to blender scripting, Although I have coding background but not experienced with blender's scripting, Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  It's aimed at people with less scripting knowledge, but it's a good introduction to blender scripting, so I recommend [_Scripting for Artists_](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_8acrgoQr1fTeIuQtkSd6BW) as the best available introduction to Blender Scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one trivial script that will rename per your (incomplete?) spec, where I've allowed for non-mesh other items (light, camera):

```
import bpy

suffix='HP'

if bpy.context.object is None:
    print('you need to select one object')
    
name_base=bpy.context.object.name

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if (obj is bpy.context.object) or (obj.type != 'MESH'):
        continue # skip selected
    obj.name=name_base+'_'+suffix
    break
```

The 'for all objects' loop breaks after renaming the first unselected object in the scene.  Or one could have name objects, and use an incrementing index like

```
suffixIdx=0
.
.
.
    obj.name=name_base+'_'+ suffixIdx
    suffixIdx += 1
    # break   # remove the break statement
```

or gussie that up by formatting the suffixIdx so that the suffix is a three digit number preceeded by zeros like `obj.name=name_base+'_'+suffix+'.{:03d}'.format(suffixIdx)`

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the help mate. :D Although Marty Fouts gave me exactly what I want. your solution is really good too. :)